# npm run devとphp artisan serveについて

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

現在作業を始める前に`npm run dev`コマンドをSSH接続したサーバ上で実行をしてから、新たなlaravelファイルを作成しています。
このサーバにバーチャルホストを割り当て、ブラウザ（chrome）から動作確認しています。

新規作成、ファイルの編集と上書き保存後、すぐにローカルのブラウザ上で動作確認ができます。

しかし、教本やhowtoのHPではweb.phpにルーティングを追加すると`php artisan serve`実行後に動作確認とあります。

1. `php artisan serve`を実行するとその後コマンド、ターミナルが使えなくなるので、 `npm run dev`を好んでいるのですが、本質的に何が違うのでしょうか？
2. また今後弊害が出る可能性はあるのでしょうか？

windows10/teraterm

Comment: タグの [tag:teraterm] は **TereTerm自体の使い方** などの質問をする際に使用しましょう。単に「使用しています」だけであれば、あまり有用なタグ付けとは言えません。